# Wordpress : How Redirect .htaccess URLs with UTF 8 chars

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect all non-subdomained requests to www while preserving the request URI.

I am using this in my .htaccess file for the redirect:

```
Redirect 301 /category/%d9%85%d9%88%d8%b6%d8%a9-%d9%88%d8%a3%d8%b2%d9%8a%d8%a7%d8%a1/%d9%85%d8%ac%d9%88%d9%87%d8%b1%d8%a7%d8%aa/ http://www.ccc.com/category/%d9%85%d9%88%d8%b6%d8%a9-%d9%88%d8%a3%d8%b2%d9%8a%d8%a7%d8%a1/
```

The problem though is that when I have a request like this:

```
/category/%d9%85%d9%88%d8%b6%d8%a9-%d9%88%d8%a3%d8%b2%d9%8a%d8%a7%d8%a1/%d9%85%d8%ac%d9%88%d9%87%d8%b1%d8%a7%d8%aa/
```

It not redirects to:

```
http://www.ccc.com/category/%d9%85%d9%88%d8%b6%d8%a9-%d9%88%d8%a3%d8%b2%d9%8a%d8%a7%d8%a1/
```

Comment: it's gets url-decoded path. Decode the local path and save the config in proper charset encoding.

Comment: @Deadooshka what you mean !! and where can do that !!

Comment: i mean `Redirect 301 /category/موضة-وأزياء/مجوهرات/ http://www.ccc.com/category/%d9%85%d9%88......` and save this htaccess in proper encoding.

Comment: iam using plugin write this url not me

Comment: I'm having the same problem
this did not help me but maybe it will work for you [http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/57711/how-can-i-create-a-301-redirect-with-non-english-characters-in-the-url](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/57711/how-can-i-create-a-301-redirect-with-non-english-characters-in-the-url)